# Add social share buttons to a gallery or group of gallery images in colorbox?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

How to add social share buttons to a gallery or group of gallery images in colorbox? Suppose there are two groups of images having 10 images each. I want to share all 10 image only on clicking just  share options on group cover image not on every image of that group.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.sharethis.com/ you will get below code. customization option is available.

HTML

```
<span class='st_sharethis_large' displayText='ShareThis'></span>
<span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>
<span class='st_twitter_large' displayText='Tweet'></span>
<span class='st_linkedin_large' displayText='LinkedIn'></span>
<span class='st_pinterest_large' displayText='Pinterest'></span>
<span class='st_email_large' displayText='Email'></span>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "56aaa941-9a11-4990-8e13-924b3bc952b7", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! But i already tried this. It only shares the images from current page not the exact image which i want to share, also i want to share whole bunch of images..